# django test database is not created with utf8

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing, utf-8

I am using `utf-8` general case insensitive for for mysql database, but `django` creates a test db with `latin collation`

I have set this:

```
TEST_CHARSET="utf8_general_ci"

TEST_COLLATION="utf8_general_ci"
```

In the settings file, but to no avail.

What else should i do?

Comment: did you validate your settings and then `syncdb` after?

Answer (score 29):

`TEST_CHARSET` and `TEST_COLLATION` are renamed to `CHARSET` and `COLLATION` and moved to `TEST` dictionary in Django 1.8:

```
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'TEST': {
        'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
    }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally that is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#test

Answer (score 12):

in settings add:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
        'TEST_CHARSET': "utf8",
        'TEST_COLLATION': "utf8_general_ci",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Please see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': <db_name>,
        'USER': <user>,
        'PASSWORD': <password>,
        'HOST': <host>,
        'PORT': <port>,
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': <test_db_name>,
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and spent hours of figuring it out until noticed that

```
TEST_CHARSET
TEST_COLLATION
```

should be a part of the DATABASES, not settings.py.
It's very easy to mix them up...

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#testing

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need something like this to create the database

```
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'TEST': {
        'CHARSET': 'utf8mb4',
        'COLLATION': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    }
}
```

But you also will want to make sure that you have something like this as well, to make sure that your tests communicate with the db with the appropriate charset.

```
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8mb4'
     }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the settings file example here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database

Comment: This is subject to link rot.  You should expend the answer to add pertinent information.